# Adding multiple images to an order form in Cognito

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there anyway to include multiple pictures or images in a form? Pictures beside the logo at the top?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload images in your [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) within the [Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/29/building-forms/form-field-reference/content-field) field:

[image]

[image]